Angular: Button text not updating despite property change
I'm encountering an issue with an Angular application where the text of a button is not updating despite changing the associated property.
In my Angular app I have a button in which I want to change the content of button dynamically. So, for that I used string interpolation.
box.component.html
<div class="box-heading">
    <h6>{{headingOne}}<i>{{headingTwo}}</i>{{buttonText}}</h6> <!-- Here, the value of buttonText is getting displayed -->
</div>
<button class="more-link">{{ buttonText }}</button> <!-- However, it is not showing here -->

So, I hard coded the content of button content
<button class="more-link">Login</button> <!-- Now, it is displaying -->

box.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-box',
  templateUrl: './box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./box.component.scss']
})
export class BoxComponent implements OnInit {
  headingOne: string = '';
  headingTwo: string = '';
  buttonText: string = 'Next'; // Even this "Next" is not showing in the button content
  forgot: string = '/forgot-password';
  myForm: FormGroup;
  

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    });

    if (this.router.url === '/login-home') {
      this.headingOne = 'Welcome to '; // This is displaying
      this.headingTwo = ' my world'; // This is displaying
      this.buttonText = 'Login'; // This is not displaying
    } 
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('Form submitted');
  }
}


Please create a reproducible example on https://stackblitz.com, as this works just fine.

Maybe some timing issue with change detection, when the template is rendered.
Move the logic to update the buttonText property to the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook instead of ngOnInit.

You probably have an error in your console that's preventing string interpolation.

The code is Ok, check upper and lower, check the console. BTW you can remove the class "more-link" and see if you can see the interpolation.

Thank you, everyone, for your time. My issue has been resolved. In my app, I hadn't been validating the password and OTP, which was preventing the code from fully loading.
